# How Can I Improve this Proof of Surjectivity between $V$ and $(V^\ast)^\ast$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

**Question**

I want to prove that $V$ is naturally isomorphic to $(V^\ast)^\ast$ without making reference to a basis.

**Note:**
$V$ is finite dimensional space.

**Attempt**

I have already shown that the map between $V$ and $(V^\ast)^\ast$ is linear and injective. What is left is to show that it is surjective.

We define $\Phi :V\rightarrow (V^\ast)^\ast$ by $\Phi (v)(f)=f(v)$ for all $v\in V$, and for all $f\in V^\ast$.

Then for every $\Psi \in (V^\ast)^\ast$, there is a $v\in V$ such that $\Phi (v)=\Psi$.

I feel there should be more to this. Is there any way I can improve this?

Comment: You have to use dimension to prove this when $V$ is finite-dimensional. It is false for infinite-dimensional vector spaces. Your proof is not a proof. You merely asserted what needed to be proved is true.

Comment: @TedShifrin I just edited the question. $V$ is finite dimensional space. How can I use dimension to do this proof?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the two vector spaces in question?

Comment: @TedShifrin No dimension is given. From the question, $V$ is finite. Also, the we shouldn’t use reference to a basis. That is all.

Comment: @MrProf Ok, you don't choose a basis. But you still know that both $V$ and $V^{**}$ have the same finite dimension. Thus any injective linear map between them is also surjective.

Comment: @Mark No, the question does not say they have the same finite dimension. Here is the question: Show that if $V$ is finite dimensional, then $(V^\ast)^\ast$ is naturally isomorphic to $V$. Here, by “natural” we mean we can exhibit the isomorphism without reference to a basis.

Comment: @MrProf The question doesn't have to say that, this is just a standard fact. The dimension of the dual space is always equal to the dimension of $V$. The space $V^{**}$ is the dual of $V^*$, so it also has the same dimension. The isomorphism is indeed natural, you didn't choose a basis anywhere in its construction.

Comment: @Mark I already wrote what I want to do in the **Attempt** I posted. Should I simply say “since $\Phi$ is a linear and injective m then it is surjective “? I still don’t get it.